# Java debugger (Netbeans) is stopping on unsuccessfull line in try block and don't allow to continue

Tags: java, postgresql

When debugging Java code using cmd.executeUpdate (cmd is preparedStatement) and executeUpdate fails, debugger breaks on this line but pressing "continue" doesn't continue the work (stays in the same line). The line is in try block and i expect it to jump to catch block to continue debugging (like in Visual Studio/C# is). What can I do to debug catch block?

Comment: Probably impossible to answer in general. Have you tried putting a break point into the catch block and run right into that?

Comment: Have you tried pressing **Step Over** instead of **Continue**? Continue will resume execution until it hits another breakpoint, Step Over will pause on the next instruction

Comment: GhostCat, yes, I tried. Still staying in this line, where it was catched. It never reaching breakpoint in catch block.

Comment: JonK, the same as above.

Comment: I pressed "continue" 6 times and it let me go. It is probably not about the number of fields because it writes (or does not) the whole record at once. It's probably some kind of disease of postgresql.jar. However, the annoying thing is that NetBeans does not open / activate the source file, you just have to search for it on foot. There is a line called "Call Stack Line" that you need to find.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, post some code and your query please;

My guess is:
seens a database access issue; 
 - check the connection to the database
 - try to execute the statement direct on the database to see if it returns any sql error;
 - check the if the db is taking too much time to respond

Comment: Ra.cavalieri, The code works as intended when run it without debugger. So the connection to the database is good. The erros is caused by db-level validation (not-null constraint violation). Without debugging works good - there is SQLException with above message. I need to catch this msg and to generate my own for user. But I wish to run this situation with debug to view various states of variables but I can't. Some time ago I read that PostgreSQL.jar has some wrappers which disturbing debugging.